# how to merge to query sets with using keyword values

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I am get two query sets,

1. queryset1:

   `<QuerySet [{'username': 'muthu12', 'user_id': 25, 'referrel_code': 'GKUPDY', 'date_joined': datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 2, 8, 47,  6, 582087)}, {'username': 'muthu123', 'user_id': 26, 'referrel_code': 'EZYSKR', 'date_joined': datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 2, 8, 47, 52, 628009)}, {'username': 'muthu1234',  'user_id': 27, 'referrel_code': 'SNMYMI', 'date_joined': datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 2, 8, 49, 6, 659250)}, {'username': 'muthu',  'user_id': 23, 'referrel_code': 'ADVKSF', 'date_joined': datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 2, 8, 44, 6, 749965)}]`
2. queryset2:

   `[{'user_id': '23', 'amount': 16.0, 'time':  datetime datetime(2023, 2, 24, 17, 45, 32,  490000)}, {'user id': '27', 'amount': 20.0, 'time':  datetime datetime(2023, 2, 24, 17, 45, 32,  490000)}]`

My expected answer below type of query set.

```
 [{'username': ' Muthu ', 
'user id': 23, 'code': 'ADVKSF', 'amount':16.0, 'date joined': datetime datetime(2023, 3, 2, 8, 44, 6, 749965)},{'username': 'muthu1234', 
'user id': 27, 'code': 'SNMYMI', 'amount':20.0, 'date joined': datetime datetime(2023, 3, 2, 8, 49, 6, 659250)},]
```

Comment: use `dict.update`

Comment: users and deposit history does not look like dicts, they look like set. Can you share your model and the exact code you have tried which did not give you the results you wanted please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested loop, but to loop over you need convert store your mutiple dictionaries into list.

**UPDATED** I guess you are just looking to update deposit list of dictionaries, thus I 've flip the nested loop as below. Where I am updating the deposit dictionaries.

**Mind** in both `users` and `deposit` dictionaries have property name `user_id`

Code:

```
u = [{'username': 'muthu12', 'user_id': 25, 'code': 'GKUPDY'}, {'username': 'muthu13', 'user_id': 21, 'code': 'GKUPDY'}]
d=  [{'amount': 16.0, 'user_id':25}]

for i in d:  #dEPOSIT's
    for j in u:  #user's
        if(i['user_id']==j['user_id']):
            print(i.update(j))
d
```

One line code:

```
[ i.update(j) for i in d for j in u if(i['user_id']==j['user_id'])]
```

Output:

```
[{'username': 'muthu12', 'code': 'GKUPDY', 'user_id': 25, 'amount': 16.0}]
```

Comment: Hi if its keyerror , you need to make sure you are using correct name.

Comment: Hi @Muthumani18 as you shared on in comment your actual data, I can see you dictionary have `user_id` but here in my solution I have `user id`. as you already have same name you can skip this step `i['user_id'] = i.pop('user id')`

Comment: I would recommend you to update your question with current input-output.